# Why is my hard drive out of space if gparted says I have 500+GB

Tags: partition, disk-usage, gparted

I recently installed Debian on my machine and made separate `/` and `/home` partitions. Yet my disk usage analyzer shows that my `/home` is inside `/`.

But `gparted` shows that `/home` is indeed in it's own partition, and has 500+ GB of free space.

I checked my `/etc/mtab` and it shows that `/home` is mounted at `/dev/sdb6` whereas `/` is mounted at `/dev/sda1`.

I don't  understand what is wrong. I'm going to keep reading about  partitioning, but I'd like to leave this question here to simmer to see if anyone has a quick answer.

I put translations in the `gparted` window just in case.

[image: What The Heck]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You split your disk into (at least) two partitions - one for your home directories (`/home`) and another for everything else (`/`). It looks like you only allocated about 10GB for `/`, which is now full. The partition mounted as your /home directory is ~621GB, with plenty of free space, but that's not where most system files go.  That's the danger of allocating too little space for `/`; if they're both on the same disk, there's rarely a good reason to split `/` and `/home`.

Answer (score 3):

There is ***a lot*** of other problems you can run into.
In my still quite short experience, I already have had at least two weird ones :

- Run out of inodes

  Inodes are limited in number, and you can't have more files than inodes, no matter your free space

  use **`df -i`** to check this one
- Have large deleted files... **still in use**

  I just retrieved 8GB on a server having free space issues.

  The facts :
  20GB drive at nearly 100% used, but only 12GB visible when using df -h on /

  The solution ? Simply reload apache (not even restart !).

  The 6GB log file I deleted one month before was still opened by apache process, and thus, disk space wasn't free.
  Use **`lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'`** to check for such files.